Why can't I just substitute with new nodes and links in this html code?
I have the following HTML code, which allows me to visualize the nodes and links stored in arrays nodesALPHV and linksALPHV. However I need to visualize entirely different nodes and links so I try to substitute within this mentioned arrays with the exact same format and it stops showing any nodes or links at all. What am I doing wrong? Or what do I need to change in order to visualize new nodes and links.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dashboard de Redes de Ransomware</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        .node {
            stroke: #fff;
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
        .link {
            stroke: #999;
            stroke-opacity: 0.6;
        }
        .link.highlight {
            stroke: #f00;
            stroke-opacity: 1;
        }
        .label {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            fill: #333;
        }
        .zoom-bar {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
        }
        .network-container {
            margin-top: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .legend {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50px;
            left: 10px;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
        .legend div {
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .legend .color-box {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
        .text-container p {
            text-align: justify;
        }
        
        .centered {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Ransomware Network Dashboard</h1>
        <div class="network-container" id="network-alphv">
            <h2>ALPHV/BlackCat Network</h2>
            <div class="legend">
                <div><span class="color-box" style="background: red;"></span>Target</div>
                <div><span class="color-box" style="background: blue;"></span>Country</div>
                <div><span class="color-box" style="background: green;"></span>Tactic</div>
                <div><span class="color-box" style="background: orange;"></span>Impact</div>
                <div><span class="color-box" style="background: purple;"></span>Recovery</div>
                <div><span class="color-box" style="background: yellow;"></span>Time</div>
                <div><span class="color-box" style="background: brown;"></span>Cost</div>
                <div><span class="color-box" style="background: pink;"></span>Size</div>
                <div><span class="color-box" style="background: gray;"></span>Severity</div>
                <div><span class="color-box" style="background: black;"></span>Ransom</div>
            </div>
            <svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
            <input type="range" min="0.5" max="3" value="1" step="0.1" class="zoom-bar" id="zoomBar">
        </div>        
    </div>
    <script>
        // Función para inicializar una red
        function initNetwork(svgId, zoomBarId, nodes, links) {
            const width = 960;
            const height = 600;

            const svg = d3.select(svgId)
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

            const zoom = d3.zoom()
                .scaleExtent([0.5, 3])
                .on("zoom", zoomed);

            svg.call(zoom);

            const container = svg.append("g");

            const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
                .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id).distance(d => 100 / d.value))
                .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))  // Aumentar la fuerza de repulsión
                .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
                .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(50));  // Evitar que los nodos se encimen

            const link = container.append("g")
                .attr("class", "links")
                .selectAll("line")
                .data(links)
                .enter().append("line")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("stroke-width", d => Math.sqrt(d.value));

            const node = container.append("g")
                .attr("class", "nodes")
                .selectAll("circle")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .attr("fill", d => {
                    switch (d.group) {
                        case "target": return "red";
                        case "country": return "blue";
                        case "tactic": return "green";
                        case "impact": return "orange";
                        case "recovery": return "purple";
                        case "time": return "yellow";
                        case "cost": return "brown";
                        case "size": return "pink";
                        case "severity": return "gray";
                        case "ransom": return "black";
                        case "central": return "lightgreen";
                    }
                })
                .on("mouseover", function(event, d) {
                    link
                        .attr("class", l => (l.source.id === d.id || l.target.id === d.id) ? "link highlight" : "link");
                })
                .on("mouseout", function(event, d) {
                    link
                        .attr("class", "link");
                })
                .call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragstarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragended));

            const label = container.append("g")
                .attr("class", "labels")
                .selectAll("text")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("text")
                .attr("class", "label")
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .attr("x", 12)
                .attr("y", 3)
                .text(d => d.id);

            simulation
                .nodes(nodes)
                .on("tick", ticked);

            simulation.force("link")
                .links(links);

            function ticked() {
                link
                    .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
                    .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
                    .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
                    .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

                node
                    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
                    .attr("cy", d => d.y);

                label
                    .attr("x", d => d.x)
                    .attr("y", d => d.y);
            }

            function dragstarted(event, d) {
                if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
                d.fx = d.x;
                d.fy = d.y;
            }

            function dragged(event, d) {
                d.fx = event.x;
                d.fy = event.y;
            }

            function dragended(event, d) {
                if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
                d.fx = null;
                d.fy = null;
            }

            function zoomed(event) {
                container.attr("transform", event.transform);
            }

            d3.select(zoomBarId).on("input", function() {
                svg.transition().duration(750).call(
                    zoom.scaleTo, +this.value
                );
            });
        }

        // Datos de ejemplo para la red de ALPHV/BlackCat
        const nodesALPHV = [
            { id: "ALPHV", group: "central" },
            { id: "Ecuadorian Army", group: "target" },
            { id: "Government Services", group: "target" },
            { id: "PriceSmart", group: "target" },
            { id: "Financial Institutions", group: "target" },
            { id: "Ecuador", group: "country" },
            { id: "Costa Rica", group: "country" },
            { id: "Mexico", group: "country" },
            { id: "Data Exfiltration", group: "tactic" },
            { id: "Ransomware", group: "tactic" },
            { id: "Service Interruption", group: "impact" },
            { id: "Disclosure of Confidential Data", group: "impact" },
            { id: "Financial Data Compromise", group: "impact" },
            { id: "System Restoration", group: "recovery" },
            { id: "Service Reconfiguration", group: "recovery" },
            { id: "Internal Audits", group: "recovery" },
            { id: "Restoration of Financial Services", group: "recovery" },
            { id: "4-6 weeks", group: "time" },
            { id: "6-8 weeks", group: "time" },
            { id: "3-5 weeks", group: "time" },
            { id: "4-8 weeks", group: "time" },
            { id: "6-10 weeks", group: "time" },
            { id: "$500,000 - $1,500,000", group: "cost" },
            { id: "$1,000,000 - $2,000,000", group: "cost" },
            { id: "$300,000 - $700,000", group: "cost" },
            { id: "$1,000,000 - $3,000,000", group: "cost" },
            { id: "Large", group: "size" },
            { id: "Medium", group: "size" },
            { id: "High", group: "severity" },
            { id: "Medium", group: "severity" },
            { id: "Not reported", group: "ransom" }
        ];

        const linksALPHV = [
            { source: "ALPHV", target: "Ecuadorian Army", value: 3 },
            { source: "ALPHV", target: "Government Services", value: 3 },
            { source: "ALPHV", target: "PriceSmart", value: 3 },
            { source: "ALPHV", target: "Financial Institutions", value: 3 },
            { source: "Ecuadorian Army", target: "Ecuador", value: 3 },
            { source: "Ecuadorian Army", target: "Ransomware", value: 3 },
            { source: "Ecuadorian Army", target: "Service Interruption", value: 3 },
            { source: "Ecuadorian Army", target: "System Restoration", value: 2 },
            { source: "Ecuadorian Army", target: "4-6 weeks", value: 2 },
            { source: "Ecuadorian Army", target: "$500,000 - $1,500,000", value: 3 },
            { source: "Ecuadorian Army", target: "Large", value: 3 },
            { source: "Ecuadorian Army", target: "High", value: 3 },
            { source: "Ecuadorian Army", target: "Not reported", value: 1 },

            { source: "Government Services", target: "Ecuador", value: 3 },
            { source: "Government Services", target: "Ransomware", value: 3 },
            { source: "Government Services", target: "Service Interruption", value: 3 },
            { source: "Government Services", target: "Service Reconfiguration", value: 2 },
            { source: "Government Services", target: "6-8 weeks", value: 2 },
            { source: "Government Services", target: "$1,000,000 - $2,000,000", value: 3 },
            { source: "Government Services", target: "Large", value: 3 },
            { source: "Government Services", target: "High", value: 3 },
            { source: "Government Services", target: "Not reported", value: 1 },

            { source: "PriceSmart", target: "Costa Rica", value: 1 },
            { source: "PriceSmart", target: "Data Exfiltration", value: 4 },
            { source: "PriceSmart", target: "Disclosure of Confidential Data", value: 3 },
            { source: "PriceSmart", target: "Internal Audits", value: 2 },
            { source: "PriceSmart", target: "3-5 weeks", value: 2 },
            { source: "PriceSmart", target: "$300,000 - $700,000", value: 2 },
            { source: "PriceSmart", target: "Medium", value: 2 },
            { source: "PriceSmart", target: "Medium", value: 2 },
            { source: "PriceSmart", target: "Not reported", value: 1 },

            { source: "Financial Institutions", target: "Mexico", value: 2 },
            { source: "Financial Institutions", target: "Ransomware", value: 3 },
            { source: "Financial Institutions", target: "Financial Data Compromise", value: 3 },
            { source: "Financial Institutions", target: "Restoration of Financial Services", value: 2 },
            { source: "Financial Institutions", target: "4-6 weeks", value: 2 },
            { source: "Financial Institutions", target: "$1,000,000 - $3,000,000", value: 3 },
            { source: "Financial Institutions", target: "Large", value: 3 },
            { source: "Financial Institutions", target: "High", value: 3 },
            { source: "Financial Institutions", target: "Not reported", value: 1 }
        ];


        // Inicializar la red de ALPHV/BlackCat
        initNetwork("#network-alphv svg", "#zoomBar", nodesALPHV, linksALPHV);
    </script>
</body>
</html>

